# Usage exceeded flood-stage watermark index has read-only-allow-delete when trying to delete document

Tags: elasticsearch

I have issue with deleting document from elasticsearch with command:
`DELETE /indexName/_doc/1`

When trying to fire above http request I am getting `too_many_requests/12/disk usage exceeded flood-stage watermark index has read-only-allow-delete`. And I understand that I need to increase disc size for my node to make it work or disable flood-stage watermark.

But when I saw `read-only-allow-delete` I thought that I can READ from given index and DELETE documents to free some space. But in realty I can only READ, why is that?
Does `...-allow-delete` means something different or is it not related to rest call and I need to clean my node by 'hand'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. You can READ the document but you can not DELETE **single document** from index. However, This will allow to delete entire index. You can read same explanation in [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-blocks.html) documentation.

> Deleting documents from an index to release resources - rather than
> deleting the index itself - can increase the index size over time.
> When index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete is set to true, deleting
> documents is not permitted. However, deleting the index itself
> releases the read-only index block and makes resources available
> almost immediately.